# Scanner Input Array sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, loops, input

I am new to java. I would like to my code to take an array of max = 100 integers from a user then it should determine if there are any duplicate integers. It should then print NO if there are duplicates and YES if all integers are unique. It should sort the input from lowest to highest then print the index number and its corresponding integer after sorting. I can get the final sort output in order also. This is what I have so far.  Any ideas on how to do this better?

```
    public static void main(String args[]){            
        Scanner takeIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers separated by comma's");           
        String startRay = takeIn.next();           
        String[] allParts = startRay.split(",");
        int L = allParts.length;           
        int[] intAllParts = new int[allParts.length];                     
        Arrays.sort(allParts);                        
        for(int n=0; n<L; n++){             
            intAllParts[n] = Integer.parseInt(allParts[n]);               
            System.out.println(" Index of " + n + " Value of " + allParts[n]);
        }            
        for(int n=1; n<L; n++){
            intAllParts[n] = Integer.parseInt(allParts[n]);    
            if(intAllParts[n-1]==intAllParts[n]){
                   System.out.println(" First duplicate found at index " + (n));
                   System.out.println(" NO");
                   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allParts) + " Array Values");
                   return;
            }                           
        }            
        Arrays.sort(allParts);    
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intAllParts) + " Array Values");
        System.out.println(" YES");           
        takeIn.close();
      }        
    }
```

**Output**

```
Enter the numbers separated by comma's

9,6,4,3,22,12,7,8,44,33,21,19,26,48,55,61,15,14,2,61,27,76,79,84,93

 Index of 0 Value of 12
 Index of 1 Value of 14
 Index of 2 Value of 15
 Index of 3 Value of 19
 Index of 4 Value of 2
 Index of 5 Value of 21
 Index of 6 Value of 22
 Index of 7 Value of 26
 Index of 8 Value of 27
 Index of 9 Value of 3
 Index of 10 Value of 33
 Index of 11 Value of 4
 Index of 12 Value of 44
 Index of 13 Value of 48
 Index of 14 Value of 55
 Index of 15 Value of 6
 Index of 16 Value of 61
 Index of 17 Value of 61
 Index of 18 Value of 7
 Index of 19 Value of 76
 Index of 20 Value of 79
 Index of 21 Value of 8
 Index of 22 Value of 84
 Index of 23 Value of 9
 Index of 24 Value of 93
 First duplicate found at index 17
 NO
[12, 14, 15, 19, 2, 21, 22, 26, 27, 3, 33, 4, 44, 48, 55, 6, 61, 61, 7, 76, 79, 8, 84, 9, 93] Array Values
```

Comment: You're only comparing each value to it's immediately previous value. What you need to do is, with nested for loops, go through each value of the array, then loop through the array again for each value, comparing every element to your current element. (But make sure you aren't comparing it to itself.)

Comment: @AndrewG the asker is already sorting the list, therefore duplicates are bound to be next to each other. There's no need to do the nested loop check.

Comment: @ADTC Yeah, I noticed that after I had posted. Oops. ;)

Comment: Unless the code isn't doing what you expect, this would be better posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `TreeSet` thus:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String in = "9,6,4,3,22,12,7,8,44,33,21,19,26,48,55,61,15,14,2,61,27,76,79,84,93";
    final SortedSet<Integer> inputs = new TreeSet<>();
    boolean dup = false;
    for (final String s : in.split(",")) {
        if (!inputs.add(Integer.parseInt(s))) {
            dup = true;
        }
    }
    if (dup) {
        System.out.println("There were duplicates");
    } else {
        System.out.println("There were no duplicates");
    }
    System.out.println("The highest number is " + inputs.last());
    System.out.println("The lowest number is " + inputs.first());
    final Iterator<Integer> iter = inputs.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; iter.hasNext(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(i + " -> " + iter.next());
    }
}
```

A `Set` guarantees unique items, `add` will return `false` if the item is already in the `Set`.

A `SortedSet` guarantees that all items in the `Set` are sorted at all times, a `TreeSet` is a implementation of the `SortedSet`.

First you loop over the input `String` and has been split by `,` and add the items to the `Set` and check the return value. We then print out whether we found a duplicate.

Then you use the `last` and `first` methods to getting the largest and smallest elements.

Finally you loop over the `Set` using its `Iterator` to spit out the elements in order and their indices. Note that a `Set` does not have indexed elements so these are "pseudo" indices.

Comment: But you need to store your duplicates somewhere to print it out.

Comment: @solvator I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader - it's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){            
    Scanner takeIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers separated by comma's");           
    String startRay = takeIn.next();           
    String[] allParts = startRay.split(",");
    int L = allParts.length;           
    int[] intAllParts = new int[allParts.length];        
    //Arrays.sort(allParts); //no use! doesn't sort numbers, it sorts strings.
    for(int n=0; n<L; n++){             
        intAllParts[n] = Integer.parseInt(allParts[n]);               
        //System.out.println(" Index of " + n + " Value of " + allParts[n]);
        //array will be sorted, so no use printing now
    }
    Arrays.sort(intAllParts); //sorts the numbers correctly.
    for(int n=0; n<L; n++){
        //intAllParts[n] = Integer.parseInt(allParts[n]); //why do this again?
        //print now, must be intAllParts, not allParts
        System.out.println(" Index of " + n + " Value of " + intAllParts[n]);
        if(n>0 && intAllParts[n-1]==intAllParts[n]){
               System.out.println(" First duplicate found at index " + (n));
               System.out.println(" NO");
               System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intAllParts) + " Array Values");
               return;
        }                           
    }            
    //Arrays.sort(allParts);    //no use
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intAllParts) + " Array Values");
    System.out.println(" YES");           
    takeIn.close();
  }        
}
```